# CakePHP: $this->paginate() and server hangs

Tags: php, cakephp, optimization, paginator

So, I have this piece of code:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Products';
var $paginate = array('limit' => 5);    // sets the number of entries per page  


function index() {      
    $this->Product->recursive = 0;
    // works up to here fine
    $this->set('products', $this->paginate());  // makes the browser hangs
    }
}
```

When I go to `../products/index` the browser just kind of hangs. It tries to load for minutes without giving any error messages, and I'm forced to restart Apache (XAMPP) or wait out a 60 seconds. The problem seems to be with `$this->paginate()` and all of the associations with Product controller. It has 2 belongsTo (belongs to smaller tables) and 1 hasOne (has one large table, 20K+ rows).

I added a `hasOne` relationship to the product model, and this seems to be causing the hanging. When I remove this relationship, the URL works and displays all items. However, this `hasOne` relationship does not cause any errors when I do for example, `../products/view/1`.

Any idea on how to make this manageable?

Comment: Sounds like the webserver hangs, not the browser.

Comment: Have you examined PHP logs, SQL logs, etc? If the Product model has a lot of associations you may want to use contain instead of `$recursive = 0`. Also, bad indexing causes slow queries, which causes the web server to hang.

Comment: @jeremyharris, could you explain a little more regarding "contain?" I think you're right. There are too many association, and the server is timing out. If you could make a separate answer, that'd be great. So, I can up it and check the answer.

Comment: I wonder, maybe you missed something in the models associations that causes some kind of endless loop while querying ..
 [] use cakephp debug toolbar for detailed sql logs that may shade some light on the hangs

Comment: @user796837 I added an answer with some information and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can look at to start debugging. The first is your logs. Check both SQL and PHP logs for slow queries and timeout errors respectively.

If your Product model has a lot of associations, I suggest using `ContainableBehavior`. Actually, I suggest always setting `$recurisve = -1;` on the model and using Containable to fetch associations. It will speed up your app dramatically. Why pull data you don't use in your views?

In your app_model, add the behavior:

```
class AppModel extends Model {

  var $recursive = -1;

  var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Then modify your find queries to grab the associated data that you want:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
  'contain' => array
    'Category',
    'Type'
  )
));
```

Where Category and Type are associated with Product. This will tell Cake to just pull that associated data.

Then look at your queries. Use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to help you analyze timing and slow queries.

These are some basic methods for speeding up your finds. There's a ton of information out there for optimizing your CakePHP app, which is what sounds like may be the problem.

Comment: OK, I see how this works now. I was already using Containable. So `$recursive=-1` in AppModel is essentially inherited in the models that extends this? I was setting `-1` in the extended models, but I guess I'd rather have it across all models and use `ContainableBehavior` when needed. I did a little test, and it seems to be the case. OOP idea doesn't come to me naturally yet.

Comment: BTW, CakePHP Debug Kit is awesome!

Comment: @user796837 It's the first thing I install when starting an app. Enable firephp for ajax debugging awesomeness, too: http://42pixels.com/blog/using-firephp-to-debug-your-cakephp-app

Comment: Yes, setting it to -1 in AppModel will make models that extend it use that setting, unless you redefine it in those models. (Cake merges some variables, like `$actsAs`, so don't get confused when they behave differently than regular OOP vars.) I always recommend setting it to -1 in AppModel right off the bat, then using Containable to grab only what you need.